# SocialMediaData doesn't show all Facebook friends

Tags: social-media

When I ran

```
SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"]
```

I used to get all of my *Facebook* friends (or at least almost all of them)--nearly 1000.  But now when I run the same code *Mathematica* only shows a network of 7 friends.  If I use "Friends" instead of "FriendNetwork", it shows 8 names.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I noticed this too, it only showed 4 for me. But I couldn't be bothered to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I believe this is because Facebook changed their API policies so now it returns a much more restricted data set than before.

Answer (score 6):

Stefan's comment is correct. *Facebook* has deprecated the API that *Mathematica* relied on to gather this information. [Official source](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/14/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/).