# Facebook Report is not available

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, social-media

Personal Analytics for Facebook doesn't work.

Some information is not available
[image]

Also there is a same problem in *Mathematica* 10.
[image]
Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

*Facebook* has deprecated the API that *Mathematica* relied on to gather this information. [Official source](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/14/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/).

Comment: Could you provide this answer also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97707/socialmediadata-doesnt-show-all-facebook-friends) so that we can close this question as duplicate?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Done.